# jQuery push/join not storing in empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am busy with a timer that is controllable by using the space bar. Press space bar x1 and it starts running, press it again, it stops and then it stores a value inside a container so that it can calculate an average of 5 eventually BUT I use the `.push()` method in jQuery to actually push it into an error called: `scores = [];` and then using a for loop that loops through the array and for some reason, it does it, but I think personally that the `.push()` function overwrites it... because without 5 values I am unable to calculate an average of 5...

**jQuery**
*Please remind that I want that the value it gets when the timers stop to be pushed into the array `scores = [];` and stays and not to be overwritten and when the array has a value of 5 times, it calculates an average of 5.*

```
var int,
     ms=0,
     s=0,
     m=0;

$('#swatch').text("00:00:00");

function swatch(){

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  int = setInterval(function(){
      var time = new Date().getTime();
      var dif = time-startTime;
      ms= dif%100;
      s = Math.floor(dif/1000)%60;
      m = Math.floor(dif/1000/60)%60;

        if(ms < 10) {
            ms = '0'+ms;
        }

        if(s < 10) {
            s = '0'+s;
        }

        if(m < 10) {
            m = '0'+m;
        }

        $('#swatch').text(m+':'+s+':'+ms);

  },1);

}

$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    var scores = [];
    var result = $('#swatch').text();


    if(e.keyCode == 32 && !int){
        swatch();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 32){
        clearInterval(int);
        int=0;
        scores.push(result);
        for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i = i + 1) {
            $('#score ol').append('<li>' + scores[i] + '</li>');
        }

        console.log(scores, scores.length);
        if(scores.length == 1) {
            console.log("You've got an average!");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're defining `scores` inside the handler, so it would overwrite itself every time, it is invoked. so, you need to declare it outside.
2. `join()` is to be used on the instance of `Array` and not on `String`
3. You need to `push` the values like `scores.push(result)`
4. `int` is a keyword which shouldn't be used as an identifier.

Comment: @user3613655 glad to have helped :) Do not forget to mark this as answer by clicking on the tick mark on my answer ;)